# Регистрация аккаунта на плей маркете

Tags: android, google-play

В общем закончил я своё первое серьёзное приложение. Теперь хочу выложить его в плей маркет. Но для этого нужно создать аккаунт продавца. Но гугл явно указывает что украинцам нельзя стать продавцом. При этом у меня есть возможность попросить людей из другой страны. И вот тут вопрос. Что именно нужно такого, что даёт возможность например россиянам создать аккаунт продавца, а украинцам нет? Ведь просто выбрать страну - не проблема. О чём просить людей из другой страны? Счёт в банке открыть или что?

Comment: @Uraty Буквально сегодня отвечал [на такой же вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/292463/android-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%B0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в налогообложении. Гугль не даст украинцам зарегить аккаунт продавца пока не договорится с властями Украины касаемо учета налогов.

Ввиду известных обстоятельств договариваться на Украине пока что не с кем и видимо не скоро будет с кем )))

**Update**

В России, например, чтобы получать денежки с продаж в Google Play надо пройти некую бюрократию включая ИНН, расчетный счет (номер карты) и проч. формальности. Далее после получения денег Google будет передавать ваши данные в налоговую инспекцию и если вы не отобразите в своей налоговой декларации полученные доходы и не заплатите как физлицо 13% налог, то скоро ждите неприятных известий от своей налоговой инспекции.

P.S. Есть [небольшая статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/191280/) касаемо деталей получения денег через Google Play